# Land cover map of Germany and Netherlands

Tags: geospatial, land-cover, map

I am looking for a high resolution land cover map in Germany and Netherlands (ideally for the whole country, but local datasets are also welcome). I know that I can get some information from Open Street map or from the Copernicus products, but I am wondering if there is an open dataset with more details (spatial resolution < 10 m or thematic details that extend the pure land cover components, including e.g. crop types (or groups of crop types), biotopes types ) that I could compare with those products. So I am looking for national/regional product and not global/european products.

Comment: Please edit and add your definition of "detail": how many classes, which spatial resolution, etc.

Comment: Earlier this year the "Land Cover Map of Europe 2017" with 10m pixel size has been published: http://www.esa.int/Applications/Observing_the_Earth/Copernicus/Sentinel-2/Land-cover_maps_of_Europe_from_the_Cloud - while pan-European maybe still interesting for you.

Comment: thank you @markusN . This map is indeed still interesting for me, but I was wondering if Germany (or regions of Germany) had "authoritative" maps of their land cover. Maybe the answer is just "no" but, for instance, France, Belgium and Luxemburg do have their "own" land cover maps. I don't speak german, so maybe I didn't find local maps that could interest me.

Comment: So, there is "CORINE Land Cover 5 ha", 2018 (CLC5-2018): https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/catalog/product/view/id/1071/s/corine-land-cover-5-ha-stand-2018-clc5-2018/category/8/?___store=default as well as this product: Digitales Landbedeckungsmodell für Deutschland, Stand 2018 (LBM-DE2018), https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/digitale-geodaten/digitale-landschaftsmodelle/digitales-landbedeckungsmodell-fur-deutschland-stand-2018-lbm-de2018.html (not available to citizens but only to federal offices).

Comment: thank you @MarkusN this comment could be a valid answer.

Comment: maybe I should add "national" in the title.

Comment: I know that there are many countries, so there could be many questions, but why not ? If I had asked national maps for all european countries, the question would have been judged too broad.

Comment: let's see if the answer provider can update their answer to include NL. If not, then we can reopen the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier this year the "Land Cover Map of Europe 2017" with 10m pixel size has been published, see http://www.esa.int/Applications/Observing_the_Earth/Copernicus/Sentinel-2/Land-cover_maps_of_Europe_from_the_Cloud .
It is a pan-European map, yet potentially interesting for you due to its high spatial resolution.

At country level, you find for Germany e.g. the following products:

- "CORINE Land Cover 5 ha", 2018 (CLC5-2018): https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/catalog/product/view/id/1071/s/corine-land-cover-5-ha-stand-2018-clc5-2018/category/8/?___store=default
- <del>Digitales Landbedeckungsmodell für Deutschland, Stand 2018 (LBM-DE2018), https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/digitale-geodaten/digitale-landschaftsmodelle/digitales-landbedeckungsmodell-fur-deutschland-stand-2018-lbm-de2018.html</del> (note: not available to citizens but only to federal offices).
- Germany 2016/2019 - Land cover based on Sentinel-2 data, 10m resolution

  - https://www.mundialis.de/en/deutschland-2019-landbedeckung-auf-basis-von-sentinel-2-daten/

For Netherlands:

- https://www.nationaalgeoregister.nl/geonetwork/srv/search?keyword=land%20cover
- maybe more...

*Edit 12/2020: added new Germany 2016/2019 - Land cover maps*

Comment: cool answer. Can you also add links to NL, since I've closed that question as dupe of this one

Comment: yes, thank you for the answer but my question has been merged by the moderator. so maybe we should split it (and the answer is valid) or I will accept it again after it has been completed for NL.